Transactional (mybatis-cdi: org.mybatis.cdi.Transactional) annotation with rollbackOnly=true not rollbacking transactions inside a Weld / JUnit 5 test

I expect this class UserMapperTest.java to run the test rollbacking the transaction (in this case for a simple insert, where the field email is unique, but the core of the problem is about the rollbacking):
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import org.jboss.weld.junit5.WeldInitiator;
import org.jboss.weld.junit5.WeldJunit5Extension;
import org.jboss.weld.junit5.WeldSetup;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestMethodOrder;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mybatis.cdi.Transactional;
import java.math.BigInteger;

@ExtendWith(WeldJunit5Extension.class)
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.MethodName.class)
@Transactional(rollbackOnly = true)
public class UserMapperTest {
    @WeldSetup
    WeldInitiator weldInitiator = WeldInitiator.of(WeldInitiator.createWeld().enableDiscovery());

    @Inject
    @TestSessionFactory
    public UserMapper userMapper;

    @Test
    public void t1_insert_user() throws Exception {
        User u = userMapper.selectUserFromId(BigInteger.ONE);
        u.setId(null);
        u.setEmail(u.getEmail() + "2");
        userMapper.insertUser(u);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(u);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(u.getId());
    }
}

The main pom.xml dependencies useful for this test are:
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>${junit.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.weld/weld-junit5 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-junit5</artifactId>
    <version>${weld.junit5.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.weld.se/weld-se-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-se-core</artifactId>
    <version>${weld-se.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.platform/jakarta.jakartaee-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>${jakartaee-api.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

with these versions:
<junit.version>5.11.0-M2</junit.version>
<weld.junit5.version>4.0.3.Final</weld.junit5.version>
<weld-se.version>6.0.0.Beta4</weld-se.version>
<jakartaee-api.version>11.0.0-M4</jakartaee-api.version>

My bean.xml is this:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="all">
   <interceptors>
      <class>org.mybatis.cdi.LocalTransactionInterceptor</class>
   </interceptors>
</beans>

This is the TestSessionFactory annotation:
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.PARAMETER;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import jakarta.inject.Qualifier;

@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER })
public @interface TestSessionFactory {
}

And this is the SqlSessionFactoryProviderTest test implementation of the SqlSessionFactoryProvider:
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import jakarta.enterprise.inject.Produces;

import org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactory;
import org.mybatis.cdi.SessionFactoryProvider;

public class SqlSessionFactoryProviderTest implements SqlSessionFactoryProvider {
    @Override
    @TestSessionFactory
    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    @SessionFactoryProvider
    public SqlSessionFactory produceFactory() {
        return ConnectionFactory.getSqlSessionFactory();
    }
}

I used to use a similar code with javax and junit 4 and worked fine. I'm trying to upgrade to jakarta and junit 5. I'm probably missing something on the WeldInitiator. The userMapper is injected correctly and the query runs correctly, simply the transaction is not rollbacked.

In the JUnit 5 extension for Weld, the test class is not a CDI bean so @Transactional, or any other interceptor applied to the test class, will have no effect. This is because back when the extension was created, it wasn't possible due to JUnit APIs. There are some Weld-JUnit GH issues detailing this, for instance this one.
JUnit has since added lots of APIs including one to provide test instances but the change would break compatibility of at least some existing tests using WeldInitiator as providing an instance sets some expectations on the test itself. That being said, I am not against implementing that; I just lack the time.
As a workaround for your scenario, you'd have to move the intercepted method login within another test bean which can be intercepted as per usual.
